# assertion fails: __is_complete_or_unbounded

Tags: c++, g++, type-traits

While compiling HHVM, the code fails due to:

```
/usr/include/c++/10/type_traits:918:52: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
  918 |       static_assert(std::__is_complete_or_unbounded(__type_identity<_Tp>{}),
```

What does `__is_complete_or_unbounded` actually do/check?

The issue occurs while constructing an object whose last member variable is as follows:

```
  value_type cell[0]
```

The constructor does not initialize this member, is this the problem? How would I initialize the value_type variable?

Comment: C++ does not allow 0 size arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, an array cannot have zero size.

From [Array declarators documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.